# $ a + \frac{1}{b} \geq b + \frac{1}{c} \geq c + \frac{1}{a} $ then $ a+\frac{1}{b} \geq 2$.

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. we put:

$x = a + \frac{1}{b}$ , $ y = b + \frac{1}{c}$ and $z = c + \frac{1}{a}$

Suppose that $x \geq y \geq z$. How can we show that $x\geq 2$?

I tried the following: $2x \geq y + z$ which means that $2x \geq b + \frac{1}{a} + 2$ because $c + \frac{1}{c} \geq 2$. But i stuck here.

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck? Please give some context oher wise the question will be closed

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried. Dont't post them in the comment.

Comment: *Hint:* Find a lower bound for $x+y+z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from what you've tried + the commend from @Martin:
$$
\begin{align}
3x \geq x + y + z = a + \frac{1}{a} + b + \frac{1}{b} + c + \frac{1}{c} \geq 6. 
\end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$
x \geq 2.
$$